# How to create a synthetic keyboard event in wxWidgets to trigger shortcuts set in a wxAcceleratorEntry?

Tags: c++, keyboard-shortcuts, wxwidgets, keyboard-events

I am using wxWebView in my application. Since this widget consumes all keyboard events internally, I have to create a synthetic keyboard event and process it. This is the code that I am using for creating a synthetic keyboard event:

```
        // create a synthetic keyboard event and handle it
        wxKeyEvent keyEvent( wxEVT_KEY_DOWN );
        keyEvent.SetEventObject( ctrl_ );
        auto key = url.substr( keyCodePrefix_.length() );
        if( key == "Escape" )
          keyEvent.m_keyCode = WXK_ESCAPE;
        else if( key == "F1" )
          keyEvent.m_keyCode = WXK_F1;
        else
          keyEvent.m_keyCode = WXK_NONE; 
        ctrl_->ProcessWindowEvent( keyEvent );
```

As you could see, I only handle `Escape` and `F1` keys for now. The type of keyboard event that I am using is `wxEVT_KEY_DOWN`. Everything works fine. According to the doc, the keyboard is processed in the widget then is sent to the application. However it does not trigger the shortcuts are set in the parent window ( that contains wxWebView widget ) via [wxAcceleratorTable](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_accelerator_table.html).

How should I create a keyboard event that trigger shortcuts in my accelerator table?

I tried to set the type of keyboard event to `wxEVT_CHAR` but it also did not work.

Update: my event handler is like below:

```
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
  public:
    MyApp();
    bool OnInit() override;
    // ...

    bool ProcessEvent(wxEvent& event) override
    {
      if( event.GetEventType() == wxEVT_KEY_DOWN )
      {
        wxKeyEvent& ke = (wxKeyEvent&)event;
        if( ke.GetKeyCode() == WXK_ESCAPE )
        {
         // handle keyboard event
        }
        event.Skip(); // this does not help!
      }
      return wxApp::ProcessEvent( event );
    }

    // ...    
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

Comment: can you show the event handler for wxEVT_KEY_DOWN? Most likely you didn't call `event.Skip()`...

Comment: You might be able to use [wxUIActionSimulator::KeyDown](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_u_i_action_simulator.html#aabcdc7be926c32bd5b68b75f16c0fcb8) to simulate the key press.  Another option would be to call the method that the accelerator would trigger directly instead of throwing the key event.

Comment: @Igor the `Skip` does not help.

Comment: @NewPagodi I tried wxUIActionSimulator but it does not even come to my handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [`sendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function of Win32 to create a synthetic key down event. It is exactly emulating keyboard events which means it triggers the shortcuts in accelerator table. Also be noticed that the keyboard event goes to the focused widget.

```
    INPUT inputs[ 2 ] = {};
    ZeroMemory( inputs, sizeof( inputs ) );
    auto key = url.substr( keyCodePrefix_.length() );
    if( key == "Escape" )
    {
      // key down
      inputs[ 0 ].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      inputs[ 0 ].ki.wVk = VK_ESCAPE;
      // key up
      /*inputs[ 1 ].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      inputs[ 1 ].ki.wVk = VK_ESCAPE;
      inputs[ 1 ].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;*/
    }
    else if( key == "F1" )
    {
      // key down
      inputs[ 0 ].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      inputs[ 0 ].ki.wVk = VK_F1;
      // key up
      /*inputs[ 1 ].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      inputs[ 1 ].ki.wVk = VK_F1;
      inputs[ 1 ].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;*/
    }
    SendInput( ARRAYSIZE( inputs ), inputs, sizeof( INPUT ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Then I think the only option will be to have some way of calling the method the accelerator entry would trigger.

Comment: It's possible but not the best solution. For that, I have to retrieve all the shortcuts and their callbacks set in the parent window which is not a good idea and also could change.

Comment: Are you sure that we cannot trigger the accelerator with a synthetic keyboard event? On what keyboard event does it work? key down, up or char? I cannot find it on the code base in git hub

Comment: Opps.  I meant to post this as a comment. Sorry for accidentally posting it as an answer.  At least on windows, I'm almost certain that it's impossible to call an accelerator method by generating an event because the key combos get [translated to WM_COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/accelerator-tables) messages by the OS before they even reach the application. I'm not sure about GTK or MacOS.  I was hoping the UI simulator could trigger that translation process to call your methods.  But since it doesn't, I just don't see any other way.

Comment: Do you know how to trigger shortcuts set by AcceleratorTable? I can get the table by `GetAcceleratorTable` function but I don't know how to trigger it. There is a `Translate` function but it needs a window message. Should I create a custom window message for `Key down` and then pass it there? If yes, how? TIA

Comment: I've never actually used that method, but based on the documentation, I believe you should create a [MSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msg) struct.  The message will be WM_KEYDOWN and the documentation for how to set the wparam and lparam is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown).